# how to manipulate Phonegap Web SQL Database

Tags: android, cordova, web-applications, web-sql

I'm developing an app with PhoneGap and I found a problem. I don't know and can't find the database file so I can manipulate it or check if it has the records and tables that I want.

Is there any app that can do that? I found that Safari and Chrome have a menu with that, but I can't find anything with that in my phone.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, but it looks like the only way to access the database is via Javascript. The Safari/Chrome web inspector are actually JavaScript with special privileges which is how they work.

Comment: Ye... I'm doing that also. But its a little bit annoying to do that all the time.

Comment: wouldn't a simple query execution then using console.log work to print the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reliable way to get at the Web SQL database is through the browser itself. There are no good "generic" tools out there to manipulate the Web SQL database that I am aware of for an arbitrary site.

With a bookmarklet, however, it would not be too challenging to create an interface to manipulate the Web SQL database on an arbitrary site and provide more options than the built-in browser interfaces.

Answer (score -1):

Try persistenceJS. It's a javascript plugin designed to make it easier to add, edit, remove tables and records in localDatabase. The documentation and the functionality are pretty good.

There's a lot of asynchronous stuff going on though, so be prepared to put a lot of your code into callbacks of callbacks of callbacks :)